# Unable to update HP Z420 Workstation BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi, windows-10-v1803

I can't update my HP Workstation BIOS, I am getting the below error:

> Error! System ROM is invalid.

I'm not actually sure what the current version was (I forgot to take a picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Business-PCs-Workstations-and-Point-of-Sale-Systems/Unable-to-update-BIOS-on-Z420-Workstation/td-p/5171165) links to a [this HP support document](https://support.hp.com/ph-en/document/c03993436), which says to update to a v1.23 Rev. A *before* updating to a later version. I'm posting the download links directly, here:

> NOTE You can download HP Z420/Z620 Workstations System BIOS VERSION: 01.23 Rev. A at:
>   https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp64501-65000/sp64701.exe
>   https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp64501-65000/sp64701.html
>   https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp64501-65000/sp64701.cva
>
> HP Z820 Workstations System BIOS VERSION: 01.20 Rev. A at:
>   https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp61001-61500/sp61312.html
>   https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp61001-61500/sp61312.exe
>   https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp61001-61500/sp61312.cva

I know its bad to post links, but this really saved my bacon and I can't attach a firmware package to this post).

Once I updated to that version, I was able to install the latest 3.XX version. I needed to install it because 3.94 had the following fix (!!!):

> Fixes an issue where system could fail to boot after upgrading to Windows 10, version 1803.